# Adding two data pandas series in Python with different index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have two data series in form

```
A

0 1

1 2

2 3

B

3 1

4 2

5 3
```

From where I want

```
C = A + B
```

to be

```
C

0 2

1 4

2 6
```

I have tried `A + B.reindex_like(A)` but it doesn't work. Everything I've tried gives me NaN's. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reset_index(drop=True)`, since A's index is default?

```
In [127]: A + B.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[127]:
0    2
1    4
2    6
dtype: int64
```

Or,

```
In [128]: pd.Series(A.values + B.values, index=A.index)
Out[128]:
0    2
1    4
2    6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think the second solution is a little more robust since if b also had indices 0,1,2 you could specify the range of values